# point projection into yx rotated plane

Tags: simulation, point, projection, depth

I want to simulate depth in a 2D space, If I have a point P1 I suppose that I need to project that given point P1 into a plane x axis rotated "theta" rads clockwise, to get P1'

It seems that P1'.x coord has to be the same as the P1.x and the P1'.y has to b shorter than P1.y. In a 3D world:

```
cosa = cos(theta)
sina = sin(theta)
P1'.x = P1.x
P1'.y = P1.y * cosa - P1.z * sina
P1'.z = P1.y * sina + P1.z * cosa
```

Is my P1.z = 0? I tried it and P1'.y = P1.y * cosa doesn't result as expected

Any response would be appreciated, Thanks!

EDIT: What I want, now I rotate camera and translate matrix 
[image]

EDIT 2: an example of a single line with a start1 point and a end1 point (it's an horizontal line, result expected is a falling line to the "floor" as long as tilt angle increases)

[image]

I think it's a sign error or an offset needed (java canvas drawing (0,0) is at top-left), because my new line with a tilt of 0 is the one below of all and with a value of 90º the new line and the original one match

Comment: Could you be more specific about what it is that you are trying to do? you have a point P1 that you want to transform in what way? you want to rotate it by theta around which axis? if you have a point at x, y, z (lets call it p1(x,y,z)) and you rotate it around the x axis by theta the new co-ordinates are p1'(x,y*cos(theta) + z*sin(theta), y*sin(theta) + z*cos(theta)) as you have put, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Mike, My case is a background image with a real street, and I draw lines in a 2D canvas (x,y) overlaid, my purpose is with a tilt angle (I think is a x axis rotation) get that line in my new "xy tilt plane", maybe I need to project in a 3D space as we said with an initial p1(x,y,0) and then project the p1'(x,y,z) to my screen 2D space...

Comment: Ok, well the equation you have described is the correct one for a rotation around the x axis by theta. If you do not get that there are a few things that you need to check. Can I ask what language you are using? The things to check are that your cos and sin functions are in radians(you can just check if sin(pi) is 0)? secondly, can you give an example printing all of your points (show all the input points and the output points along with theta and the intermediate points) You are right that p1.z should be 0 and p1'.y should be = p1.y*cosa

Comment: I'm using Java. I convert into radians well. I edited with an example

Comment: Your calculations are all correct, given the numbers you have posted (and given that your tilt angle is in degrees rather than radians). Could you describe what it is that you think should happen? This does exactly what I expect it to so the problem must be that you expect it to do something different, I could give an explanation for what is occuring if you think that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation you are performing is correct if you would like to perform a rotation around the x axis clockwise. If you think of your line as a sheet of paper, a rotation of 0 degrees is you looking directly at the line.

For the example you have given the line is horizontal to the x axis. This will not change on rotation around the x axis (the line and the axis around which it is rotating are parallel to one another). As you rotate between 0 and 90 degrees the y co-ordinates of the line will decrease with P1.y*cos(theta) down to 0 at 90 degrees (think about the piece of paper we have been rotating around it's bottom edge, the x axis, at 90 degrees the paper is flat, and the y axis is perpendicular to the page, thus both edges of the page have the same y co-ordinate, both the side that is the "x-axis" and the opposite parallel side will have y=0).

Thus as you can see for your example this has worked correctly.

EDIT: The reason that multiplying by 90 degrees does not give an exactly zero answer is simply [floating point rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Rounding_modes)

Comment: Here's an explanation for why what you are doing is correct for a rotation around the x-axis, let me know what you were expecting to happen or whether you need any clarification on the points.

Comment: Ok , calculation was good but as I said the system origin is at top-left corner so the solution was the P1.y = canvasHeight - P1.y and then P1'.y = canvasHeight - P1'.y, I got it! The problem now is do the perspective, because the 2D projection of the point is an orthogonal one... Thanks Mike for your help and support!

Comment: No problem, glad you got the solution, if the answer helped just click accept.